# how to use spop command with count if set have that much (count) element in set

Tags: redis

Let suppose I want to pop 3 elements from the set, how I ensure that only pop if 3 elements present in a set otherwise return any error or  other msg

> How to use "spop" command with "count" argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to call `SCARD myKey` to test the number of members, and based on the result call `SPOP`.

`SPOP` with `COUNT` will return up to `COUNT` members, meaning if your set only has one or two, they'll be SPOPed and returned.

You probably want to do this with **one atomic operation**. So you have to use [Lua Scrips](https://redis.io/commands/eval):

```
EVAL "if redis.call('SCARD', KEYS[1]) >= tonumber(ARGV[1]) then return redis.call('SPOP', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) else return redis.error_reply(KEYS[1]..' does NOT have at least '..ARGV[1]..' members') end" 1 myKey myNumber
```

Let's take a look at the script:

```
if redis.call('SCARD', KEYS[1]) >= tonumber(ARGV[1]) then 
    return redis.call('SPOP', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) 
else 
    return redis.error_reply(KEYS[1]..' does NOT have at least '..ARGV[1]..' members')
end
```

`KEYS[1]` refers to the key parameter, the set you're interested in. It is important to pass keys through parameters for your script to be supported in a Redis Cluster.

`ARGV[1]` is an additional argument to pass your number of desired members, in your question, it is 3.

The script is run atomically server-side within Redis, and it is *compiled* only once as Redis caches it internally.

You can use `SCRIPT LOAD` to load the script and then reuse it with `EVALSHA`, to also improve networking performance.

Comment: Nice answer... although in this case I'd just `SMEMBERS` + `DEL` the set ;)

Comment: `SMEMBERS` is O(n), a performance risk if the set can grow large. 
Also, by the time you `DEL`, chances are there are new members. So you may want to `SREM` one by one instead.

Comment: Can I do this in JavaScript nodejs?

Comment: Sure, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44676974/executing-redis-eval-command-to-run-lua-script-in-nodejs